# Is it possible to visualise a code?

Tags: matlab

Is there any possibility to visualize(as written) codes that you put which contain mathematical formulas? I have some codes that I will use for some modelings but I can realise what she did since it's too long and complicated.

Comment: So you want to visualize the coded mathematical formulas using mathematical symbols?

Comment: Consider debugging... Step-by step execution really helps to understand the code

Comment: yeah,I would like to visualise using mathematical symbols(if that is possible)

Comment: Can you give an example? It's unclear to me what you are asking..

Comment: I haven't come across any application/package in MATLAB which can do that automatically for you.

Answer (score 3):

The closest to what you want I can think of is [`pretty`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/pretty.html) and [`latex`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/latex.html), that operate on [symbolic](http://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/index.html) expressions.

Example:

```
>> syms x

>> y = x^3/3 + 2*x^2 + x - 5

y =

x^3/3 + 2*x^2 + x - 5

>> pretty(y)

   3 
  x       2 
  -- + 2 x  + x - 5 
  3

>> latex(y)

ans =

\frac{x^3}{3} + 2\, x^2 + x - 5
```

The latter, pasted on an [online latex interpreter](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php), produces

[image]